# Python can't write to dataframe from dict. Simple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'0-10': -0.04, 
         '10-20': -0.01, 
         '20-30': -0.03, 
         '30-40': -0.04, 
         '40-50': -0.02, 
         '50-60': 0.01, 
         '60-70': 0.05, 
         '70-80': 0.01, 
         '80-90': 0.09, 
        '90-100': 0.04}

stat = pd.DataFrame()

for x,y in dict1.items():
    stat[x] = y
```

I try to write dict values to my dataframe and associate the column name to the keys. But my output is this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50, 50-60, 60-70, 70-80, 80-90, 90-100]
Index: []
```

Tried it multiple times. No syntax errors. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example output

Comment: The output is an empty Dataframe. instead of a row of my dict values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=[0])`

or

`df = pd.DataFrame([dict1])`

```
print(df)
    0-10  10-20  20-30  30-40  40-50  50-60  60-70  70-80  80-90  90-100
0 -0.042  -0.01  -0.03  -0.04  -0.02   0.01   0.05   0.01   0.09    0.04
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great! Any idea why my way didn't work though?

Comment: oh great, please accept if that's what you want. Your approach didn't work because `stat[x]` is not how you populate a `df`, that's how you collect column `x`

Comment: Can shorten this to `pd.DataFrame([dict1])`.

Comment: @johnboy I believe it is because you start off with an empty data frame. Then, you assign a scalar to create your column (i.e. stat[x] = y). By definition, since it is a scalar, it'll try to broadcast to whatever shape `stat` has. Since the shape has 0 lines, it broadcasts to zero and never actually shows up in your df. Take a look at [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more insights on how that happens ;]

Comment: @rafaelc thanks for that explanation, won't make this mistake again.